# Are dynamic properties officially supported on all class instances?

Tags: php

To my surprise today I found out, that I can do something like this in PHP:

```
class Customer
{
    public $name;
}

$customer = new $customer;

// No error:
$customer->email = 'test@example.com';
```

Now i wonder: Is this a valid PHP feature? I've check the PHP manual, but could not really find this covered anywhere.

#### Background

I'm writing a client for a complex SOAP service and will use the `classmap` option in `SoapClient` to map some SOAP classes to local PHP classes. I do this only for specific SOAP classes because I need to add some related code to those classes.

If I could avoid having to define all the SOAP properties, it would make my PHP classes much more lightweight and easier to maintain, as some of the SOAP service datatypes get updated quite frequently.

#### UPDATE

To make this more clear: I know that this is not really best practice and I'm aware of the risks. The question is really **not** how to write *good code* or whether this is a good idea.

The question is really:

- Is this an officially supported feature in PHP?
- While it works now, will it also work in PHP 7.x, 7.1.x, etc?
- Where is this documented?

Basically it behaves as if there was an internal default implementation of `__get()` and `__set()` in each class:

```
private $_props = [];
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->_props[$name] = $value;
}
public function __get($name)
{
    if(!isset($this->_props[$name])) {
        trigger_error('Undefined property 'get_class().'::$'.$name);
    } else {
        return $this->_props[$name];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use magic functions `__get` and `__set` which can help you achieve implement dynamic properties. If I'm not mistaken, the above example should have issued a warning.

Comment: Does your code work? If yes (it should) then it is a valid PHP feature.

Comment: @Mjh I know about `__get()` and `__set()` - but that wasn't the question. I'm really trying to find out, if the behavior I described is reliable and documented somewhere. There's no warning.

Comment: The **reliable** behaviour is to use methods I mentioned. They are **made** for such purpose. Now, you can of course ignore my comment, research this behaviour and create properties dynamically, but can you obtain a list of properties then in an easy manner? You can't. Using `__get` and `__set` you can easily maintain an array of dynamically added properties, retrieve them at any point, serialize to XML any way you see fit etc. and that's **exactly** why these methods exist.

Comment: @Mjh All you say is not really related to my question. I'm not asking for best practices or the like. I perfectly know about the risks and use `__get()` and `__set()` otherwhere in my code. I really only want to know: Is what I said above a valid PHP feature.

Comment: It is a valid feature. Unless you try to retrieve a property that hasn't been declared. Which you will do, since you're dabbling with SOAP. Hence, I tried to shorten your pain by suggesting to do it properly, because we're talking about 5-6 lines of code in total, so your dynamic properties will work forever, be it setting or retrieving them. Good luck with your project. Note: PDO uses this feature when retrieving records from the database into a class.

Comment: @Mjh Again: I'm perfectly aware of all this. Just trust me, that in this case, things may get much easier for me. I'm absolutely aware that my code will need many `isset()` to check for the property before reading it. But I'll never access any property from outside the class. Adding magic getters/setters unneccessarily complicates things. I'm only interested in a couple of well defined properties of the SOAP response and don't care about all the rest.

Comment: It's your project, your code and your time. If you say that it's easier for you to implement a bunch of issets instead of a trait that helps you with `__get` and `__set` then that sums it up. It's true that I've no clue how you'll use this so I won't try to convince you otherwise. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Setting / getting undefined properties is not uncommon in PHP and is often used with `StdClass` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting. For example you would get a StdClass object with `json_decode()` which is a native PHP function, so it is totally valid. In your case using it is fine since you are just passing data to SOAP and the data itself in not defined by your application but by the SOAP calls (wsdl?)

In other cases i would always recommend defining all the properties in the class and not to use random not defined properties. That way not only your code is cleaner but potential errors can also be better recognized by your IDE.

Comment: Well, that's not really answering my question. I know that this works with `stdClass`. The question is really: Does this also reliably always work with other classes and is this documented somewhere. I don't want to rely on obscure undocumented behavior.

Comment: `stdClass` has no special functionality, it is just an empty class with assigned properties, that were not defined before. Thought i can not find any documentation on undefined properties in the official PHP doc, this is how `PHP` works. If you want to be safe (and prevent any PHP notices) you can check the existence with http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php first

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal PHP. Declaring a public property like that can help prevent issues with undefined var notices when doing stuff like `if($this->name)` or for setting a default value, but it's not necessary.

Comment: So can you point me to some documentation? Of course you can assign a value to an undefined variable. But I wasn't aware that this also works for undefined class properties. I would have expected a warning (which you get, when you try to read the property before assigning a value.)